# the value was changed when saving to database in Zabbix 3.4.12

Tags: tomcat, zabbix

I am trying to use zabbix lld to monitor tomcat 7.0.x in zabbix 3.4.12.

I can see the data is get correctly from agent and server can also receive the data correctly from log file when I enable debug information. But the strange issue is: the data can't be saved to database correctly, all these data are saved as 0 in database.

For example: in zabbix_server.log

the zabbix server cant got the value of currentThreadCount which is 46, the value of maxThreads is 5000, but these two values of keys were saved as 0 in history_uint table,

How could I go about this:

Below is the log info form zabbix_server.log:

```
18636:20181017:180652.642 trapper got '{"request":"agent data","data":[{"host":"server203_108","key":"jmx.tomcat.item[\"Catalina:type=ThreadPool,name=http-bio-8082\",currentThreadCount,18082]","value":"64","clock":1539770810,"ns":197292171},{"host":"server203_108","key":"jmx.tomcat.item[\"Catalina:type=ThreadPool,name=http-bio-8082\",maxThreads,18082]","value":"5000","clock":1539770810,"ns":641525117}],"clock":1539770812,"ns":642146384}'
18636:20181017:180652.642 In recv_agenthistory()
18636:20181017:180652.642 In process_hist_data()
18636:20181017:180652.642 In process_mass_data()
18636:20181017:180652.642 End of process_mass_data()
18636:20181017:180652.642 End of process_hist_data():SUCCEED
18636:20181017:180652.642 In zbx_send_response()
18636:20181017:180652.642 zbx_send_response() '{"response":"success","info":"processed: 2; failed: 0; total: 2; seconds spent: 0.000127"}'
18636:20181017:180652.642 End of zbx_send_response():SUCCEED
...
18646:20181017:180653.078 query [txnlev:1] [insert into history_uint (itemid,clock,ns,value) values (23726,1539770810,197360432,0),(23727,1539770810,641593378,0);]
```

Comment: the problem is that the value always is saved as zero in history_uint table, what's the reason?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Finally I got the root cause that the item has a Preprocessing setting as "Change per second", the value has been change (preprocess) before saving to database.